# FreeBSD 7.2 problem with libjpeg.so.10

Tags: freebsd, port, imagemagick

Greetings all.
I am not well experienced FreeBSD user and somtimes being completely stuck.

While installing webalizer port couple days ago, I did something bad (I am not sure what certainly).
Today I have discovered that Imagemagick stopped working, says `Shared object "libjpeg.so.10" not found`

With heavy googling I have found that it's `jpeg` port responsibility.
But I can't get it updated to jpeg-7. I tried to update ports collection using `configure` utility, but it remain being jpeg-6b_7.
What can I do to update jpeg port to jpeg-7?
Or any other solution to make imagemagick work (thugh I have already deinstalled it)?

BTW, I can't install portupgrade family utilities because of error while installing ruby18 package. `*sigh*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure that your ports tree is up to date:

```
portsnap fetch
portsnap update
```

Then, I would recommend getting portupgrade working, so that you can avoid these sorts of problems in the future:

```
cd /usr/ports/lang/ruby18
make clean; make deinstall; make install; make clean
cd /usr/ports/databases/ruby-bdb
make clean; make deinstall; make install; make clean
cd /usr/ports/ports-mgmt/portupgrade
make clean; make deinstall; make install; make clean
```

Once you have portupgrade working correctly, you can use it to fix any ports which are busted. For example, to get `graphics/jpeg` working again, you can do the following:

```
portupgrade -frR graphics/jpeg
```

This will take a while, since it will reinstall all ports which depend on `graphics/jpeg` and all ports which `graphics/jpeg` depends upon. Normally I wouldn't do that, but if you get your ports tied up in knots it can be a good way of getting back to a consistent state.